# Magento Commerce Cloud Upgrade 2.4 issue

Tags: upgrade, magento2-cloud, composer-update

I am trying to upgrade to Magento 2.4 but I get the following error running `composer update`:

```
    - magento/framework 101.0.0-rc21 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.0-rc22 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.0-rc23 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.0-rc30 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.0 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.1 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.2 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.3 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.4 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.5 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.6 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.7 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.0 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.8 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.2 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.9 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.10 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0|~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.2-p2 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.11 requires php ~7.0.13||~7.1.0||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mageworx/module-layered-navigation-meta 1.2.8 requires mageworx/module-layered-navigation 1.2.8 -> satisfiable by mageworx/module-layered-navigation[1.2.8].
    - mageworx/module-layered-navigation-meta 1.2.8 requires mageworx/module-layered-navigation 1.2.8 -> satisfiable by mageworx/module-layered-navigation[1.2.8].
    - mageworx/module-layered-navigation 1.2.8 requires magento/framework >=101.0.0 <103 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p1, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 101.0.11, 102.0.2-p2, 101.0.10, 102.0.3, 101.0.9, 102.0.2, 101.0.8, 102.0.1, 102.0.0, 101.0.7, 101.0.6, 101.0.5, 101.0.4, 101.0.3, 101.0.2, 101.0.1, 101.0.0, 101.0.0-rc30, 101.0.0-rc23, 101.0.0-rc22, 101.0.0-rc21].
    - mageworx/module-layered-navigation 1.2.8 requires magento/framework >=101.0.0 <103 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.5, 102.0.4-p1, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 101.0.11, 102.0.2-p2, 101.0.10, 102.0.3, 101.0.9, 102.0.2, 101.0.8, 102.0.1, 102.0.0, 101.0.7, 101.0.6, 101.0.5, 101.0.4, 101.0.3, 101.0.2, 101.0.1, 101.0.0, 101.0.0-rc30, 101.0.0-rc23, 101.0.0-rc22, 101.0.0-rc21].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.5-p2, 103.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.4-p2, 103.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.5, 103.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.4-p1, 103.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3-p1, 103.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.4, 103.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 103.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[103.0.0, 102.0.5-p2].
    - magento/module-weee-staging 100.4.0 requires magento/framework 103.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[103.0.0].
    - magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.0 requires magento/module-weee-staging 100.4.0 -> satisfiable by magento/module-weee-staging[100.4.0].
    - magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.4.0 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition >=2.4.0 <2.4.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.4.0].
    - Installation request for magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.4.0 <2.4.1 -> satisfiable by magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.4.0].
    - Installation request for mageworx/module-layered-navigation-meta 1.2.8 -> satisfiable by mageworx/module-layered-navigation-meta[1.2.8].
```

Running `composer self-update` does not help. It says `You are already using composer version 1.10.13 (stable channel).`
Should I remove the `composer.lock` file?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `mageworx/module-layered-navigation-meta` package, which says:

```
mageworx/module-layered-navigation-meta 1.2.8 requires mageworx/module-layered-navigation 1.2.8 -> satisfiable by mageworx/module-layered-navigation[1.2.8].
```

It requires `mageworx/module-layered-navigation` version 1.2.8

```
mageworx/module-layered-navigation 1.2.8 requires magento/framework >=101.0.0 <103 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2,...
```

It requires `magento/framework` version  >=101.0.0 and <103.0.0.

But Magento 2.4 requires `magento/framework` version 103.0.*

Your installed version of Mageworx Layered Navigation (1.2.8) does not compatible with Magento 2.4. The lowest version of that module which compatible with Magento 2.4 is 1.3.0. You need to upgrade that module to version 1.3.0 or above.

Comment: thanks :-), that solved the issue!